# Create output spaces in R Shiny UI in server function dynamically

Tags: r, shiny

I want create output spaces in UI part of Shiny conditionally. If the variable in server changed, the output spaces should be defined in UI.
library(shiny)

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel("main panel", textOutput("ts_txt_main"))
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({  
    for (i in 1:10) {
      output[[paste0("ts_txt",i)]<- renderText({ "Some_text" })
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I need `textOutput("ts_txt_main")` to be changed or extended to  `textOutput("ts_txt1"), textOutput("ts_txt2"), textOutput("ts_txt3"), textOutput("ts_txt4"), textOutput("ts_txt5"), textOutput("ts_txt6"), textOutput("ts_txt7"), textOutput("ts_txt8"), textOutput("ts_txt9"), textOutput("ts_txt10")`

Comment: Put the logic for this inside `output$ts_txt_main <- renderText({...})`.  The final line of the `{...}` should be the string you want displayed.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDewar . I did it as you mentioned.